# getcwd Error throughout System

Tags: mac, bash, unix, terminal

I seem to be getting a getcwd error suddenly throughout my system. Thoughts anyone.

```
shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you deleted the directory you are in?

Try `cd /` or `cd ~`.

Comment: This is generally the problem when pwd fails. `cd` alone should work, as it seems to default to the home directory. Attempts to pushd a now non-existent directory fail better: they pop the no-more dir and push the current dir.

Comment: rare, and cd will resolve, but what is it, if not that the current directory was deleted? Is this something that sinks suspicions, a filesystem problem creeping up on you?